# Why I can apply JS/Jquery function to a button specific ID, but can't link to his class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to apply a function when a button is pressed, but sometimes the button is appended, so I tried to apply the function to his class. The problem is that I can only make the function work when I link it to the button ID, when I link the class nothing happens. This happens to the button that is appended and to the normal button as well.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.createCustomLayer', function () {
 alert("Alert");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light form-control" id="createCustomLayer" class="createCustomLayer" style="margin-top: 32px;">Create a custom layer</button>
```

If I change the `.createCustomLayer` for `#createCustomLayer`, all works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't have multiple `class=""` move `createCustomLayer` into `class="btn btn-light form-control"`, so it looks like `class="btn btn-light form-control createCustomLayer"`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.createCustomLayer', function () {
 alert("Alert");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light form-control createCustomLayer" id="createCustomLayer" style="margin-top: 32px;">Create a custom layer</button>
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. Thank you!

Comment: @leonardofmed No problem, Happy to help.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you have more than one *class* attribute in the element. If you have multiple *class* attribute in the same element then except the first one all are simply ignored:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.createCustomLayer', function () {
 alert("Alert");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light form-control createCustomLayer" id="createCustomLayer" style="margin-top: 32px;">Create a custom layer</button>
```